# What is the highcharts-more file needed for?

Tags: highcharts

This should be an easy one for someone... I expect it's obvious, but I've looked in various places on highcarts' site and google and simply couldn't find an answer...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From highcharts.com: (http://www.highcharts.com/articles/2-news/46-gauges-ranges-and-polar-charts-in-beta , http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server)

> To avoid bloating the Highcharts core JavaScript, we deploy the new chart types and features in a separate file called highcharts-more.js. We will continue to build extended functionality in this file, and reserve highcharts.js for common tasks and visualizations.

Basicly, they added some extra functionality on top of Highcharts without modifying it's core code.
Including this file, also allows you to use some types of charts which don't exist in the "original" highcharts such as bubble, range and pollar charts:

> ...Save highcharts.js or highstock.js for stock charts, highcharts-more.js (for bubble, range, polar charts)....

Comment: Link? Do they have a full list of what's in it and what isn't?